# Last child with some .class of its parent

Tags: html, css

With `span:last-of-type` I can select last `span` element of its parent. But is there any solution to select last element with any `.class` of its parent? Like:

```
div .myclass:last-of-type {
   ...
}
```

from:

```
<div>
    <span class="myclass">One</span>
    ...
    <i>text</i>
    <b class="myclass">Two</b> <!-- this i want select -->
    <b>more text</b>
    <i>text</i>
    <span>Three</span>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Chovanec/pen/lkojd

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're trying achieve is currently not supported in CSS. `nth-of-type` and friends act solely upon the tag name.

Comment: pity this is what I thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.  [`:nth-child`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#last-of-type-pseudo) and its ilk only apply to *elements*, not just general selectors.  Therefore, `.myclass:last-of-type` will only work the way you want it to if the last `<b>` is selected.  In your example, it won't work.  Your only option is to change your markup somehow.